# API Resource comes blank

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

in my API project that I have coded, I have data in 2 tables, "follows" and "followers". I want to customize it with Resource and export it as json, but the user information is blank. What do you think is the reason?

**FollowerResource**

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user' => new UserResource($this->user),
        ];
    }
```

**FollowResource**

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user' => new UserResource($this->user),
        ];
    }
```

**UserController**

```
     public function followUser() {
        $follows = Follows::all();
        return response()->json(FollowResource::collection($follows),200);

    }
    public function followerUser() {
        $followers = Followers::all();
        return response()->json(FollowerResource::collection($followers),200);

    }
```

**OUTPUT**

***Follow and Follower Route***

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user": null
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user": null
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "user": null
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "user": null
  }
```

*Thank you in advance for your help. I wish you good and healthy days.*

Update

**USER RESOURCE**

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'user_id'       => $this->id,
            'email'         => $this->email,
            'description'   => $this->description,
            'first_name'    => $this->first_name,
            'last_name'     => $this->last_name,
            'full_name'     => $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name,
        ];
    }
```

Update Two

**Followers DATA**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1240 ▼
  #items: array:11 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Followers {#1241 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "followers"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "user_id" => 3
        "created_at" => "2002-08-01 03:26:41"
        "updated_at" => "2020-08-13 11:32:28"
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => App\Models\Followers {#1242 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\Followers {#1243 ▶}
    3 => App\Models\Followers {#1244 ▶}
    4 => App\Models\Followers {#1245 ▶}
    5 => App\Models\Followers {#1246 ▶}
    6 => App\Models\Followers {#1247 ▶}
    7 => App\Models\Followers {#1248 ▶}
    8 => App\Models\Followers {#1249 ▶}
    9 => App\Models\Followers {#1250 ▶}
    10 => App\Models\Followers {#1251 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show the code for userResource, which will be very helpful for resolution of your issue

Comment: I updated on the topic. Thanks for your help.

Comment: And bro can you please output the dd on this $follows = Follows::all(); variable

Comment: I want to see what data $follow contains

Comment: I added it to the subject, my friend. The "followers" and "follow" configuration is the same. The user is "user_id" associated with "id".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your follow resource to this

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
         'id' => $this->id,
         'user' => new UserResource($this->user_id),
    ];
}
```

In your Follow Resource file add this line

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        $user = User::find($this->user_id);
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user' => new UserResource($user),
        ];
    }
```

And let me know if it's helpful

Comment: Hello, gave an error like this: "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: @alihan.dev It's because you are not fetching the user's value in follow Resource, I was assuming that you are doing that

Comment: I don't know much about this. Can you help me?

Comment: Thank you. My problem is solved. I wish you good work and healthy days :)